# useSelector does not work when I set two state inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Why doesn't my code work? I am trying to separate these two things into one, but useSelector does not work.

This code works

```
  const st = useSelector((state) =>
     state.or.st
   );

   const ter = useSelector(
     ({ main }) => main.st.ter
  );
```

This code does not work

I want to put these two things in one useSelector and not in two?

Comment: In the first example you're returning values inside the `useSelector` callback. The second example doesn't return anything.

Comment: But again no work i will update question

Comment: `main` can't be the second parameter but `state.main`

Comment: Hmm where is problem herE?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1: Incorrect Function Usage**

The `useSelector` hook expects a [function that takes a single parameter](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/4d384029e3fa0355e762f40409a5dac4358a3de3/src/hooks/useSelector.ts#L25) `state`.

`state` is the whole state held by redux.

This would mean that your combine function should look more like the following:

```
const { units, organistationTerminology } = useSelector(state => {
    organistationTerminology = state.main.organisation.terminology;

    units = state.organisationStructure.units.sort(
        (a, b) => a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder
    );

    return {
        organistationTerminology, 
        units
    }
});
```

**Issue 2: Changing Reference**

The combined selector function returns a new object which will have a difference reference each time the selector function is computed.

The default comparison used by `useSelector` to detect a change between values is a reference comparison.

This will result in your component being rerendered on any store change regardless of whether `state.main.organisation.terminology` or `state.organisationStructure.units` is updated.

**Issue 3: Computation in Selector**

Selectors will run on each store change and the resulting value will be compared with the previous value to determine whether a component rerender needs to be triggered.

This means that even if `state.organisationStructure.units` never changes you will still be running a sort on every store change.

Computations should, where possible, be preformed outside of the selector function.

**Issue 4: Sort on State Value**

`sort()` sorts the array *[in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)* which would be mutating your state.

**Conclusion**

Selector functions should be kept as simple / quick as possible as they will be run on every store change.

Pulling multiple values from separate sections of state in one selector usually adds more complexity than it is worth.

My suggestion would be to keep it simple:

```
const units = useSelector(state => state.organisationStructure.units);

const organistationTerminology = useSelector(state => state.main.organisation.terminology);

const sortedUnits = [...units].sort();

// OR the sort can be memoized using units as a dependency;
const sortedUnits = useMemo(() => [...units].sort(), [units]);
```

If this is something you will be reusing in a number of components you could wrap it up in a custom hook:

```
const useTerminologyAndSortedUnits = () => {
    const units = useSelector(state => state.organisationStructure.units);

    const terminology = useSelector(state => state.main.organisation.terminology);

    const sortedUnits = useMemo(() => [...units].sort(), [units]);

    return {
        units: sortedUnits,
        terminology
    }
};

// The following can then be used in any of your function components
const { units, terminology } = useTerminologyAndSortedUnits()
```